# Separate string of xml using dom4j

Tags: java, xml-parsing, dom4j

So this is my scenario. I have this xml example.

```
<persons>
 <person>
  <name>Person1</name>
  <lastName>Person1LastName</lastName>
  <address>Foo<address>
  <contact>Bar</contact>
 </person>
 <person>
  <name>Person2</name>
  <lastName>Person1LastName</lastName>
  </person>
</persons>
```

My question is how can I separate person with address and contact? I want to return it as string. Is there a way to know if element is exist using select nodes?

```
//query elements with address and contact
document.getRootElement().selectNodes(//person/[contains address and contact]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Element> elements = document.selectNodes("//persons/person/address and //persons/person/contact");
```

The above code retrieve the elements which have address and contact as sub-elements.